# Make panes visible using Swing

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have this GUI that I am working on, but I cannot get the layout to look quite right.  It should look like this:

[image]

Here is my code with only the GUI showing and the start of some actions commented out:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ATM {  
private JFrame frame;
private JButton withdrawl;
private JButton deposit;
private JButton transfer;
private JButton balance;
private JRadioButton checkingButton;
private JRadioButton savingsButton;
private JTextField input;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ATM frame = new ATM(); 
    frame.createFrame();
}

public void Frame(){
    createFrame();
}

private void createFrame(){

    frame = new JFrame("ATM Machine");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(300,220);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    withdrawl = new JButton("Withdrawl");
    deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    transfer = new JButton("Transfer");        
    balance = new JButton("Balance");
    checkingButton = new JRadioButton("Checking");
    savingsButton = new JRadioButton("Savings");
    input = new JTextField();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(checkingButton);
    group.add(savingsButton);
    controls(contentPane);
frame.setVisible(true);
}   

private void controls(Container contentPane) {

   GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
   contentPane.setLayout(layout);
   layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
   layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
   layout.setHorizontalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
           .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(withdrawl)
    .addComponent(transfer)
    .addComponent(checkingButton)
    .addComponent(input)) 
           .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)  
    .addComponent(deposit)
    .addComponent(balance)
    .addComponent(savingsButton)
   ));       
   layout.setVerticalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
       .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)  
    .addComponent(withdrawl)
    .addComponent(deposit))
       .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)  
    .addComponent(transfer)
    .addComponent(balance))
       .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)               
    .addComponent(checkingButton)
    .addComponent(savingsButton))
    .addComponent(input));
   contentPane.add(withdrawl);
   contentPane.add(deposit);
   contentPane.add(transfer);
   contentPane.add(balance);       
   contentPane.add(checkingButton); 
   contentPane.add(savingsButton);
}}
```

It now looks like this:

[image]

Comment: BTW - 'ATM Machine' means 'Automatic Teller **Machine Machine**'..

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

1. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Most of your names are correct but some are not. Be consistent.
2. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow the conventions from the Java API.

Follow Java conventions.

```
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
Container inputPane = frame.getContentPane();
```

There is only one content pane. Assigning the content pane to two different variables doesn't mean you can add more components to the content pane.

In your Controls method you use:

```
contentPane.setLayout(layout);
```

which changes the layout manager. So know any component you add the content pane must use the You are then changing the GroupLayout along with its contraints.

In your InputPane method you use:

```
inputPane.add(input);
```

But you don't specify any GroupLayout constraints so the layout manager doesn't know what to do with the component.

I don't see any reason to have two methods to build the components. From your image I see a single panel with multiple components since you decided to use a GroupLayout. Get rid of this method and just add the component to the GroupLayout in your Control method.

```
contentPane.add(Withdrawl);
contentPane.add(Deposit);
contentPane.add(Transfer);
contentPane.add(Balance);       
contentPane.add(CheckingButton); 
contentPane.add(SavingsButton);
```

Also you can't just add the components like that to the content pane because you already tried to add each of those components to the content pane by using the GroupLayout. It seems to me like your code is a combination of code generate by an IDE and some manual code. I suggest you skip the IDE and write the layout code yourself.

So maybe a GridBagLayout will be easier to use than the GroupLayout. Read the section from the SWing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: made some changes in the code above, but it's still not right.  I was trying to get it all in one method originally.

Comment: @dsmracr29,  `I was trying to get it all in one method originally.` - that is a good approach. Keep the cod e to build the GUI in one method. Keep working on it. It takes time to best understand which layout manager (or combination of layout manager) to use. Again the tutorials have example of creating a form with multiple components. I suggest you start with working code. The tutorial demos will show you how to better structure your code.